# Shouldn't this code make the whole picture black?

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, p5.js

In p5.js, I am trying to process each pixel of an image for a personal project so I thought I would start out slow and just try to make each pixel black. For some reason the screen is just staying white and I have no idea why the pixels aren't being updated. Here's the code:

```
var Canvas;
var srcImg;
var defaultImg = "http://i.imgur.com/ARg0OOy.jpg";

function preload() {
srcImg = loadImage(defaultImg);
}

function setup () {
  createCanvas(srcImg.width,srcImg.height);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  srcImg.loadPixels();
  for (var x = 0; x < srcImg.width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < srcImg.height; y++) {
      var loc = x + y*srcImg.width;
      srcImg.pixels[loc] = color(224,29,29);
    }
  }
  console.log(loc);
  console.log(srcImg.width);
  console.log(srcImg.height);
  console.log(srcImg.width * srcImg.height);
  srcImg.updatePixels();
  //image(srcImg, 0,0,srcImg.width, srcImg.height);
}
```

Also, if I uncomment the last line, I see the original picture and it is cut off at the top (and it hasn't turned every pixel black). You can see for yourself [here.](https://codepen.io/alexhutman/pen/JJjear) Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Edit: I tried even doing one row of pixels to be a vibrant red color and the reason I'm getting a white screen is because no matter what color I set the pixels to, they become white... Also, when I tried making the whole row this red color, it stopped at about 1/4 the way through as shown [here](https://codepen.io/alexhutman/pen/NgqgME) (and is still white). I  don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making all of the pixels black, but then you're drawing `srcImage` on top of those black pixels. So all you see is `srcImage`.

Try commenting out the `image(srcImg, 0,0,srcImg.width, srcImg.height);` line to see the black pixels.

Comment: Hmm, but wouldn't `updatePixels()` overwrite the original `srcImg`, making it black? Either way, I tried commenting it out and now nothing appears on the screen.

Comment: @AlexHutman Why would `updatePixels()` overwrite the original `srcImage`? And nothing is exactly what should appear on the screen- you're only drawing black pixels.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I was thinking that `updatePixels()` would alter the pixels of the image, not the canvas. Also, when I said nothing appears on the screen, I meant I have a completely white screen. There is no black.

Comment: @AlexHutman If you want to update the pixels of the image, you'd want `srcImage.loadPixels()` and whatnot. As it stands, your code is updating the pixels on the screen. If you're not seeing the black pixels, then I'd suggest debugging to see exactly which pixel locations you're updating.

Comment: I just tried changing `loadPixels()` to `srcImg.loadPixels()`, `pixels[loc]` to `srcImg.pixels[loc]`, and `updatePixels()` to `srcImg.updatePixels()`. I also logged the value of `loc` and it corresponded to the product of the dimensions of my image (minus 1 of course). For some reason I am still just seeing a white screen. Should I try Processing 3.3? I'm on 3.3.4 right now. I apologize if this is frustrating, this is my first time doing anything with Javascript or websites so I'm slowly learning.

Comment: @AlexHutman Processing and P5.js are two different things. It's not frustrating at all. Could you please post the image you're using? Or better yet, can you please put together a CodePen that shows your P5.js sketch running? (and showing the behavior you're seeing)

Comment: Sure! [Here it is](https://codepen.io/alexhutman/pen/JJjear) -- I couldn't add assets because that's a pro feature so I just uploaded the picture to Imgur and made it load the image from there. The screen is white and if you uncomment the last line the picture shows up (although the top is missing for some reason) instead of it being black.

Comment: Hmm, I tried just making a row of pixels red and if you look at the CodePen in the "Edit:" portion, it only affects about 1/4 of the pixels and makes them white, not red. Is there something I'm missing? This code is only a couple lines long and it seems like it should work because it's (in theory) taking every pixel in the first row, setting the color to red, then updating it.

Comment: @AlexHutman Are you sure you're correctly calculating the `loc` index into the pixels array? Please see [this page](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image) in the P5.js reference for an example.

Comment: Jeez. I got too used to Processing and didn't realize that the `pixels` array works a bit differently. Thanks for your help!